# Using $or selector, There is no index available for this selector

Tags: indexing, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-mango

I'd like to retrieve

- document with `_id` of `1`

  **OR**
- document with `value === 13` AND `anotherValue === 56`

Error:

> There is no index available for this selector.

This is my query:

```
{
  "selector": {
      "$or": [
          {
              "_id": "1"
          },
          {
              "value": "13",
              "anotherValue": "56"
          }
       ]
   }
}
```

Indexes setup:

```
Your available Indexes:
special: _id
json: value, anotherValue
json: _id, value, anotherValue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this query you need to add a selector to get all the IDs like so:

```
{
    "selector": {
        "_id": {"$gt":null},
        "$or": [
            {
                "_id": "1"
            },
            {
                "value": "13",
                "anotherValue": "56"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can learn more here:

https://cloudant.com/blog/mango-json-vs-text-indexes/

And this SO post:

[index and query items in an array with mango query for cloudant and couchdb 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107333/index-and-query-items-in-an-array-with-mango-query-for-cloudant-and-couchdb-2-0/34137925#34137925)

Alternatively, you can add a text index on all fields:

```
{
    "index": {},
    "type": "text"
}
```

And then your original selector should work.

Comment: thanks! Any chance you could have a look at this one (similiar, but using `sort`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868228/perform-sort-on-field-thats-not-primary-index