# Perform sort on field that's not primary index

Tags: indexing, couchdb, cloudant

Error:

```
No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.
```

I've tried creating indexes on `anotherValue`, `_id+anotherValue`, but no difference.

This is my query:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": { "$gt": null },
    "$or": [
          { "_id": "10" },
          { "value": "10", "anotherValue": "1234" }]
  },
  "sort": [{"anotherValue": "desc"}]
}
```

Indexes setup:

```
Your available Indexes:
special: _id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a desc index on anotherValue:

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      {"anotherValue":"desc"}
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

and change your query to this:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "anotherValue": { "$gt": null },
    "$or": [
      { "_id": "10" },
      { "value": "10", "anotherValue": "1234" }
    ]
  },
  "sort": [{"anotherValue": "desc"}]
}
```

Note: Your original query would also work if you added a text index on all fields:

```
{
  "index": {},
  "type": "text"
}
```

Comment: thanks! trying to avoid `{"index": {}, "type": "text"}` because off perf implications