# pouchDB and querying by date or date range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pouchdb

I'm currently able to successfully fetch data from my database, create an index, and then get the most recent 7 records using pouchDB in a react.js progressive web app.

My hurdle currently is querying by dates. So with my current code, I'm getting all data, creating an index and then I'm getting only the 7 latest records so that I can map the data. But I'm trying to figure out how to use my moment date for the current day: `newestDate: moment(this.currentDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`
and use this to say "get the most recent record from each day over the last 7 days"

So effectively, I have records which have the format of `{caloriesBurned:"250", caloriesConsumed:"1450", createdAt:"2020-03-05"}` and I want to be able to modify my query to get only one record for each day, starting today and going back for 7 days

How can I properly do this in pouchDB with this code:

```
fetchData = () => {
    this.setState({
        calorieElements: null,
    });
    this.state.caloriesDB.db.allDocs({
        include_docs: true,
    }).then(result => {
        const rows = result.rows;
        console.log('this is a row');
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
            calorieElements: rows.map(row => row.doc),
        });
        console.log(this.state.calorieElements);
    }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

  getMax = () => {

    this.state.caloriesDB.db.createIndex({
      index: {
        fields: ['_id','caloriesBurned', 'createdAt']
      }
    }).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.setMax();

   }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  setMax = () => {
    this.state.caloriesDB.db.find({
      selector: {
        $and: [
          {_id: {"$gte": null}},
          {caloriesBurned: {$exists: true}},
          {caloriesConsumed: {$exists: true}},
          {createdAt: {$exists: true}}
        ]
      },
      fields: ['caloriesBurned','caloriesConsumed', 'createdAt'],
      sort: [{'_id':'desc'}],
      limit: 7
    }).then(result => {

      const newDocs = result.docs;
      const docCalories = newDocs.map(x => +x.caloriesConsumed - +x.caloriesBurned);

    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Clarification -there is only one record per day, correct?

Comment: I was hoping for a solution with multiple per day (get the last record of the day in that case) but I'd accept a solution for one per day, as I can update the day's record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the surely ways to achieve what you desire.  I've kept the code as close to yours as possible.  The key is the ordering of the index fields, with `createdAt` being first to facilitate sort.

```js
let db;
// demo 
initDb().then(() => {
  // get last 7 days on 2020-03-09
  return queryCreatedAt("2020-03-09", 7, 'desc');
}).then(result => {
  // display results.
  console.log(result);
})

// query docs by createdAt 
function queryCreatedAt(date, limit, order) {
  return db.find({
    selector: {
      $and: [{
          createdAt: {
            $lte: date
          }
        },
        {
          caloriesBurned: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          caloriesConsumed: {
            $exists: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    sort: [{
      createdAt: order
    }],
    limit: limit,
    fields: [
      'createdAt',
      'caloriesBurned',
      'caloriesConsumed'
    ]
  });
}

// init db instance
function initDb() {

  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });

  return db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall()).then(() => {
    return db.createIndex({
      index: {
        fields: [
          'createdAt',
          'caloriesBurned',
          'caloriesConsumed'
        ]
      }
    })
  })
}

// get test docs
function getDocsToInstall() {
  return [{
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-27"
    }, {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-28"
    }, {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-29"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-01"
    }, {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-02"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "950",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1950",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-03"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-04"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-05"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-06"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "450",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1450",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-07"
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "550",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1550",
      "createdAt": "2020-03-08"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.find.js"></script>
```

For supporting multiple entries on the same date, I would *denormalize* the indivdual documents presented to day (24 hour) based documents with entries in an array like this.  I prefer using UTC over string dates - it's a personal choice.

```
{
  entries: [
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "350",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1350",
      "createdAt": 1586357069
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "450",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1450",
      "createdAt": 1586357080
    },
    {
      "caloriesBurned": "550",
      "caloriesConsumed": "1550",
      "createdAt": 1586357140
    }
  ]
}
```

For inspiration as how to index and query items in an collection refer to the SO article [Index and query items in an array with mango query for cloudant and couchdb 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107333/index-and-query-items-in-an-array-with-mango-query-for-cloudant-and-couchdb-2-0)